# how to retrieve list of model from another model that has a ForeignKey relationship

Tags: django, python-2.7, api

I am A junior dev tring to build an app that saves an asset to each employee

employees can have many assets

employees can see lists of their own assets only

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Asset(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # added_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='asset_added_by')
    description = models.TextField()
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='asset_categories')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='asset_images', null=True, blank=True)
    stock =models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    number_of_employees = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name    


class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='employee_image', null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username   

class Registration(models.Model):
    employees = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    assets = models.ForeignKey(Asset, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    date_from = models.DateField()
    date_to = models.DateField()
```

I am confused with relationships is this correct?

How can i get list of assets for each employee?

Answer (score 0):

Give `Asset` a ForeignKey relation to `Employee`? Then, by default, the employee's assets are referenced as `Employee.asset_set.all()`.

If an Asset can have many employees as well as an Employee having many assets, then its a ManyToMany relation not a ForeignKey.

Keeping one employee from seeing other employee's assets is a matter of restricting the views. I would imagine that the asset-list-view would retrieve the Employee linked to the current logged in User, if that's what the User model  is.

Comment: Give Asset a ForeignKey relation to Employee ----> when adding a new asset , i don't want to add an employee

Comment: That's usually handled by making the ForeignKey with null=True. You can then save it without any employee until you are ready to give it to somebody. Also probably on_delete=models.SET_NULL so it doesn't vanish when the employee leaves the organisation.

Comment: thanks it works but i don't understand how to git the list of asset for an employee using this  Employee.asset_set.all()

Comment: It returns the `Asset` objects related to an employee instance: use it with an instance, not the class. `e = Employee.objects.get(...)` then for example `for asset in e.asset_set.all():`

Comment: view.py class EmployeeDataView(RetrieveAPIView):
 queryset = Employee.objects.all()
 serializer_class = EmployeeDataSerializer
 lookup_field = 'id'
 lookup_url_kwarg = 'employee_id'

Comment: where to use for asset in e.asset_set.all():??

Comment: In the view where you want to display the assets for the current user, or in its template (with `{%for`)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like right now you don't really have a grasp of model relations, or specifically how your models should be related. Have you tried creating a form of relational diagram? I.e. a drawing (you can do this just on paper) that displays the lines between objects. (you could look into [UML class diagrams](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/uml/uml_class_diagram.htm) for instance)

Anyhow, what you are trying to set up is something like this:

```
User  -<-  Employee  ->  Department
               |    
               ^
               |
Category -<- Asset
```

I assume here that each asset can only belong to 1 employee. If that is indeed what you want, what Nigel222 says is almost correct, though you should write the relation at the asset object instead (`employee=models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCASDE)`).
If that is not the case you should add a ManyToManyField instead.
`assets = models.ManyToManyField(Asset, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Comment: yes each asset can only belong to 1 employee i put ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)) it works. Thanks alot